# How to maintain multiple API versions in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Does anyone have ideas on maintaining multiple versions of your API when using sails.js? Imagine a simple example like:

```
// Request
GET /api/v1/catVids?min_view_count=10000

// Response
[{"video_title": "top cat fails"}, {"video_title": "funny-ass cats"}]
```

Users are actively consuming v1 of the API but something has now changed in the requirements that will break existing functionality. For example, an attribute name change. So now we need to utilize a different controller to fulfill requests for this new behavior. What I would like to do is have both APIs co-exist so backwards compatibility is not broken.

```
// Request
GET /api/v2/catVids?minimum_view_count=10000

// Response
[{"title": "top cat fails"}, {"title": "funny-ass cats"}]
```

However, I'm unsure on the best way to implement this. One way I think it could work is to use the following directory setup within the sails app:

```
api/
|-- controllers/
|---- v1/
|------ CatController.js
|---- v2/
|------ CatController.js
|-- models/
|---- v1/
|------ Cat.js
|---- v2/
|------ Cat.js
```

I'm just wondering if anyone else has ran into a similar scenario or has any suggestions on the topic.

Comment: So your saying just your controllers need versioning, not the entire app?

Comment: Yea just the API would need to be versioned for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Are you running blueprint routes for you all your actions or do you have custom routes? Also, are your running any type of file version control right now? Like Git or SVN? Cause you can prefix all of your blueprint routes in sailsjs (http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/blueprints.js.html) and then you can tag different versions in what ever version control system your running. Then you just have to figure out deployment. You would have to run a sails server for every version.

Comment: I'm using the routes built by sails on boot. I am using git as a VCS but I should be able to run multiple versions of the API simultaneously from the same app. /api/v1 routes would just go to different controllers than /api/v2 routes.

Comment: I don't think Model can be run from sub folders at this time, and I know that the current blueprints will no do this as well. 

Your comment "should be able to run multiple versions of the API ... from the same app", is a little assertive. Why should you be able to? 

You can easily write your own blueprints and simply create models that are suffixed. UserV1, UserV2, UserV3. But like I said you would have to create your own blueprints.

Comment: You would want to if you had third party customers that use your website.  It is easier to manage and deploy one code branch than multiple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get away with putting your controllers in subdirectories as in your example, because nested controllers are fully supported by Sails.  However, nested models are not fully supported because of the ambiguity they would cause (see [this comment](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2099#issuecomment-51873491) on the matter).  If you put two model files both named **Cat.js** in separate subfolders, they'll collide and the second one will overwrite the first in memory when Sails lifts.

That's sort of an academic point though, since you'll need some way to distinguish between your two model versions anyway in code.  That is, in your v1 controller you'll want to make sure you're referencing your v1 `Cat` model, and likewise for v2.  The simplest solution would be to go with a scheme like you have in your example, but add a suffix to your models (or at least everything after v1):

```
api/
|-- controllers/
|---- v1/
|------ CatController.js
|---- v2/
|------ CatController.js
|-- models/
|---- v1/
|------ Cat.js
|---- v2/
|------ Cat_v2.js
```

The subfolder for the models will be ignored by Sails, so to make sure your blueprints work the way you want, you can add a `_config` property to your controllers to force them to use the correct model.

**api/controllers/v1/CatController.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    model: 'cat'
  },
  ...
}
```

**api/controllers/v2/CatController.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    model: 'cat_v2'
  },
  ...
}
```

### Update (for Sails 1.0)

The usage of `_config` in a controller is no longer valid in Sails 1.0.  Instead, you can use the [`parseBlueprintOptions` config function](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/1.0/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.md#using-parseblueprintoptions) to set which model a blueprint operates on, e.g.:

```
parseBlueprintOptions: function(req) {

  // Get the default query options.
  var queryOptions = req._sails.hooks.blueprints.parseBlueprintOptions(req);

  // Add the _v2 suffix to the `using` property.
  queryOptions.using = queryOptions.using + '_v2';

  return queryOptions;

}
```

Comment: This google group thread may answer the question differently : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/8_e5CeHQjtY
IMO Sails should allow API versioning OOB. Has there been any progress or is this still a valid method.

Comment: Is there anyway to support routing based on version headers? i.e. Accept: version=2

Comment: To add middleware, edit your policies.js as:  'v2/UserController': {
    'create': ['isAuthenticated']
  },

Comment: Can somebody please tell me if i have to maintain two different routes for this.

For eg I have two versions with controller
v1/UsersController.js,
v2/UsersController.js 

Now in my routes.js do i have to keep two different routes  like

     'get /v1/users': 'v1/UsersController.get'

`'get /v2/users': 'v2/UsersController.get'`