# Best practice to change default blueprint actions in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm looking for an answer to what is the best practice to customize default sails.js CRUD blueprints. The simple example of what I mean is let's say I need to create `SomeModel`, using standard blueprint `POST \someModel` action, and also I want to get information about authenticated user from `req` object and set this property to `req.body` to use `values.user.id` in `beforeCreate` function:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    // some attributes
  },

  beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
    // do something with values.user.id
  }
};
```

I'm very new to sails.js and don't want to use anti-patterns, so I'm asking for inputs on what is the right way to handle such cases. Also it would be great to have some good resources on that topic.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for overriding the blueprint API](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?overriding-blueprints)?

Comment: Yes, of course. My question is not about how to override the blueprint API. It is about what is the best way to achieve my goal (how to do that correctly).

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you.  Are you saying that you know that the best way to achieve your goal is to override the blueprint API, and you have read the docs for how to do that (i.e. by creating a `create` action in your controller) but you want to know what code to put in that action?

Comment: I'm curious about what option to choose: override `create` action at my controller, create a new custom action in the controller and add it to route config, create a policy and apply it to create action at the particular controller or maybe there are some other options I'm not aware about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options open to you which you've identified, and as usual, it depends on your use case. Here are some thoughts on the three options you listed in your comment:

1. Override `controller/create` - Of the three, this is the best option because it doesn't clog up code in `routes` or `policies` for a single instance.
2. Write `controller/action` and add to `config/routes.js` - While this works, it defeats the purpose of using blueprints, and you have to do all the code in option 1 plus making your `routes` code messier.
3. Apply a policy for a single `create` action - To do this, you will not only have to clutter up your `/policies` folder but also your `policies.js` file. This is more code AND it puts the logic for one controller method in two separate places, neither of which is the controller.

Out of these three, option 1 is the best because it contains the code to its context (the controller) and minimizes written code. This is assuming that you only want to alter the `create` method for one model.

---

Side note:

As an example of how your use case determines your implementation, here is how I've set my Sails app up which has a few REST routes, each of which responds differently based on the user calling the route (with a valid Facebook token):

1. Only uses blueprint action routes (not blueprint REST routes)
2. First goes through the policies: 
   `'*': ['hasFBToken', 'isTokenForMyApp', 'extractFBUser', 'extractMyAppUser']` which store `fbuser`, `myappuser`, and other variables in `req.body`
3. At this point, my controller function (e.g. `controller.action()`) is called and can access information about that user and determine if it has the correct permissions to do CRUD.

Pros of this system:

- All code for each CRUD operation is contained within its controller function
- Minimal to no code in `routes.js` (no code) or `policies.js` (one line) or `/policies`
- Works well with [API Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167885/how-to-maintain-multiple-api-versions-in-sails-js) (e.g. `controllers/v1.0/controller.js`), which is much easier to do with versioned controllers than versioned models. That means that I can create a new API version and simply by creating a controller in `/v2.0` with a function `action()`, calls such as `POST /v2.0/controller/action` will exist with no extra routing needed.

Hopefully this example helps illustrate how design decisions were made to offer functionality like API versioning and consolidate code in its specific context.